# How to list all running workitems in Forge - Design Automation for Revit?

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I would like to get running workitems to track progress of the posted workitems.

It is possible to get details to a given workitem by providing an ID, like this:

`https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/workitems/{{workitemId}}`

but I have posted multiple jobs, and using postman, only the last ID gets saved to an environment variable.

I tried getting the generic /workitems endpoints without query strings, but the result was that "The requested resource does not exist."

It would be nice to get a bit more documentation about the specific endpoints, I have read
[The developers_guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/)
but could not find an answer.

I would expect a rest api to give back a list of workitems, just like it does it for activites or appbundles.

Answer (score 2):

Design Automation doesn't have an API to list WorkItems. We only keep WorkItem's reports for 3 days.
You can use [this API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-id-GET/) to get details of a given workitem by providing its id.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How can you then cancel jobs that you sent? You need to save the ids you sent?

Comment: Yes, you can call https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/workitems-id-DELETE/ to cancel the jobs by id.

Comment: So if multiple instances are calling the api and you want to ensure that you do not exceed 100 requests per minute you would have to keep track of that yourself?

Comment: In the above case, you will get the error of "TooManyRequests", asking for retrying.